# WiFi SSID not visible on Andriod Things (Raspberry Pi 3B)

Tags: wifi, android, android-things

I'm trying to connect my Raspberry Pi's to a WiFi network without success. Ethernet connection works flawlessly, but as I attempt to connect to WiFi using ADB as mentioned here, nothing happens. I have also tried to use the Android Things Setup Utility without success as can be seen in the terminal output.

When I try to connect through the menu option while running with a monitor connected, my particular network is not visible, e**ven though my work's corporate networks are visible in the same menu**. It should be noted that other devices are able to connect to the WiFi in question, and using any corporate network is not possible the project.

I have also tried

- Using a cell phone as hotspot with similar result
- Unplugging the ethernet cable when attempting to find networks(through the monitor interface)
- Changing between password/open network
- Both 2.4G and 5G
- Changing SSID from uppercase to lowercase
- Manually changing the /data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf but cannot find any OS files on the SD card.
- Reinstalling OS image.

*I'm running Google iot_rpi3 v1.0.3*

There seems to be no documentation on this issue, has anyone else encountered this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

It appears as if the Wi-Fi list in the GUI only can display at most **three** network SSID's. This lead to the corporate networks effectively 'jam' access to my Wi-Fi as the list appears to be sorted by signal strength, and my network's RSSI was weaker than the corporate one's.

Will investigate further and possibly post a bug report to the public issue tracker.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.